# Does Mandarin have any argots/cants like Pig Latin in English or Šatrovački in Serbian?

Tags: games

In English, Pig Latin is a way of speaking (or less commonly writing) to disguise the content in a simple way to make it difficult for outsiders or people not familiar with Pig Latin to understand what is being said.

E.g in Pig Latin one takes the first consonant sound of a word, moves it to the end and adds the phoneme -ay. Words starting with a vowel gain the suffix "way".

cat -> atcay,
dog -> ogcay,
fish -> ishfay,
otter -> otterway.

I am vegan; I don't eat meat -> Iway amway eganvay; Iway ontday eatway eatmay.

Does Chinese (specifically Mandarin) have anything like this?

Comment: Any suitable answers here: https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/54904/4136?

Comment: Those look interesting, but they seem to be for calculation by a computer rather than in real-time by a human.

Answer (score 0):

No, as far as I know.
In some meme videos, some may drop the vowels and perform memes to make them even more hilarious, but not in daily conversations.